# Как перезалить приложение, которое находится на рассмотрении в AppStore?

Tags: appstore, xcode, ios, objective-c

Вчера опубликовал приложение в appstore, и сегодня понял что нужно чуть чуть  изменить. Сейчас приложение находится на рассмотрении. Могу ли я его как-нибудь перезалить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, в itunes connect в настройках приложения, Вы можете сделать "Reject Binary", это будет кнопка синяя справа вверху, на том же месте, где вы нажимали "Ready for upload binary". После этого сможете залить свое приложение еще раз.